# How can I add a newline after match is found

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I want to add a newline after number 64, using awk or sed, in ping output such as this:

```
64 bytes from 170.198.42.128: icmp_seq=1 ttl=60 time=83.4 ms 64 bytes from
170.198.42.128: icmp_seq=2 ttl=60 time=76.6 ms 64 bytes from 170.198.42.128: icmp_seq=3  
ttl=60 time=70.8 ms 64 bytes from 170.198.42.128: icmp_seq=4 ttl=60 time=76.6 ms --- 
170.198.42.128 ping statistics --- 4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 
3000ms rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 70.861/76.924/83.493/4.473 ms
```

I've tried

```
cat file | sed 's/64/\n/g'
```

but this replaces the number 64. I want to break the pattern and display the ping command pattern starting with 64 properly.

I tried using append and insert mode ..but not using them correctly

Comment: o thanks that works just added the 64 back .n is there no otehr way not using the subsitution

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In a substitution, `&` in the replacement will be replaced with whatever matched. So:

```
sed 's/64/\n&/g' file
```

Comment: thanks this works . is there no other way using substitution  I mean not using s option? Is there no other way of just adding a line after pattern 64

Comment: @theuniverseisflat this and the other currently posted solution would insert a newline in the middle of an IP address or any other text that contains `64`, e.g `111.164.111.111` or `time=64.5` would both get split by newlines - is that really what you're looking for?

Comment: This gives very different result from what `ED` has in his post.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're referring to. There's no sample output in the question, I'm just going by his description.

Comment: @EdMorton to match only whole words you could type: `s/\<64\>/\n&/g`. The `\<` or `\>` or `\b` for gnu sed look for word boundaries so it would match `111 64 111` and `111.64.111` but not `111.164.111`. One could exclude patterns like `.64.` with a negative lookbehind but sed doesn't support lookarounds.

Answer (score 7):

This `sed` command should work with both gnu and BSD sed versions:

```
sed $'s/64/\\\n&/g' file

64 bytes from 170.198.42.128: icmp_seq=1 ttl=60 time=83.4 ms
64 bytes from
170.198.42.128: icmp_seq=2 ttl=60 time=76.6 ms
64 bytes from 170.198.42.128: icmp_seq=3
ttl=60 time=70.8 ms
64 bytes from 170.198.42.128: icmp_seq=4 ttl=60 time=76.6 ms ---
170.198.42.128 ping statistics --- 4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time
3000ms rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 70.861/76.924/83.493/4.473 ms
```

**Update:** Here is gnu awk command to do the same:

```
awk '1' RS='64' ORS='\n64' file
```

Comment: Are you using `$''` to work for both GNU and BSD/OSX? Also, it looks like you need the `g` flag at the end.

Comment: Yes that is the reason to make it work on BSD sed also which won't like `\n` otherwise. Also thanks I added `g` flag now.

Comment: Is `$'s/64/\\\n&/g'` REALLY the correct syntax or is it just working by accident? To get a literal newline in shell is just `$'\n'` so I'd have expected your script to be something like `'s/64/\'$'\n''&/g'`

Comment: @EdMorton: Yes, `$'s/64/\\\n&/g'` works: it represents the _entire_ `sed` script as opposed to just a newline (`$'\n'`) as an ANSI C-quoted string, but, as you can see, it introduces additional escaping needs: `\ ` is must be represented as `\\ ` (whereas the `\n`, as in the single-char. version, `$'\n'`, expands to an actual newline).

Comment: Thw `awk` gives a single `64` without a new line as the last line.

Comment: Using awk I am actually getting exact same output as shown above in my answer.

Comment: Thank u all . the awk and sed commands work. Also anubhava no matter what number I put in place of 1  awk '1' still workd...

Comment: Yes that is true any non zero value will work for awk command.

Comment: @anubhava, could you try to answer this please? It is the same case as what you wrote: https://superuser.com/questions/1249497/sed-needs-n-to-append-new-line

Answer (score 2):

This might be more like what you really need (uses GNU awk for multi-char RS):

```
$ gawk -v RS='^$' '{gsub(/[[:space:]]+/," "); gsub(/(\<[[:digit:]]+\> bytes|---)/,"\n&"); sub(/^\n/,"")}1' file
64 bytes from 170.198.42.128: icmp_seq=1 ttl=60 time=83.4 ms
64 bytes from 170.198.42.128: icmp_seq=2 ttl=60 time=76.6 ms
64 bytes from 170.198.42.128: icmp_seq=3 ttl=60 time=70.8 ms
64 bytes from 170.198.42.128: icmp_seq=4 ttl=60 time=76.6 ms
--- 170.198.42.128 ping statistics
--- 4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 3000ms rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 70.861/76.924/83.493/4.473 ms
```

Comment: +1; since the input contains no _empty_ lines, this should in principle also work with POSIX-only features, if you use `-v RS=`. However, POSIX extended regexes due not recognize `\<` and `\>` or any other form of word-boundary assertion. However, in this particular case it's OK to simply omit them (even in the GNU version). Thus: `awk -v RS= '{gsub(/[[:space:]]+/," "); gsub(/([[:digit:]]+ bytes|---)/,"\n&"); sub(/^\n/,"")}1' file`

Comment: (Except for my spelling: 'due' for 'do'?)

Answer (score 0):

For more general case (add a text **and** newline after/before the match) I recommend using the following commands.

This approach is better than /a sed parameter, because /a does not work on some operating systems or old sed versions.

If REPLACE_STR is empty it will add just a newline after/before the PATTERN_STR, that is the asked question is a particular case (PATTERN_STR=64, REPLACE_STR=).

Adds REPLACE_STR string as a new line *after* the matched string PATTERN_STR:

```
sed $'s/PATTERN_STR/&\\\nREPLACE_STR/' file
```

Adds REPLACE_STR string as a new line *before* the matched string PATTERN_STR:

```
sed $'s/PATTERN_STR/REPLACE_STR\\\n&/' file
```